# Как открыть второе окно при нажатии на кнопку?

Tags: wpf

Как при нажатии на кнопку открывать диалоговое окно,помимо главного(MainWindow)?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Используйте `Show`, вместо `ShowDialog` для окон

```
Window1 a = new Window1();
a.Show();
Window1 b = new Window1();
b.ShowDialog();
```

Answer (score 1):

Открытие окна подразумевает создание объекта класса символизирующего окнo. Это важно понимать для работы с ним. При открытии нового окна вы визуализируете объект класса.

```
Window windowA = new Window();
windowA.Show();
```