# как в wpf изменить стартовое окно с MainWindow на другое?

Tags: c#, wpf, visual-studio

нужно, чтобы вначале появилось окно login, но настройки, где меняется окно так и не нашел

Comment: Я думаю, что MainWindow вам и нужно реализовать как окно Login, а затем создать другие необходимые окна или фреймы.

Comment: Вот простой и достаточный ответ: [Change Startup Window](http://stackoverflow.com/a/17067487/5275890) Не будет лишней вот эта ссылка: [WPF - choose startup window based on some condition](http://stackoverflow.com/a/10276293/5275890).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

В файле `App.xaml` в поле `StartupUri`.

```
<Application x:Class="Restaurant.App"
         xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
         xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
         xmlns:ViewModel="clr-namespace:Restaurant.ViewModel"
         StartupUri="MainWindow.xaml">
</Application>
```

Это если при старте приложения, а вообще `MainWindow` оно на то и Майн - чтоб основная работа приложения в нем была, грузитесь, а потом поверх (или внутри раз у нас WPF) пораждаете диалог с запросом логина и пароля - и дальше работаете.

Comment: так и сделаю, спасибо

Answer (score 0):

Я думаю, ваш вопрос можно решить следующим образом. Сперва, в `public MainWindow()` вы прописываете код, который предоставлен в [данном ответе](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/466853/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%BA%D1%80%D1%8B%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%B2%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B5-%D0%BE%D0%BA%D0%BD%D0%BE-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B8-%D0%BD%D0%B0%D0%B6%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B8%D0%B8-%D0%BD%D0%B0-%D0%BA%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%BF%D0%BA%D1%83) на Stack.
На форму Login помещайте TextEdit для ввода логина и пароля. Button, который проверит валидность и закроется только в том случае, если всё верно.
Так же, для примеров работы с окнами в WPF вы можете прочитать:

- [metanin.com](http://metanit.com/sharp/wpf/20.2.php)
- [ptofessorweb.ru](https://professorweb.ru/my/WPF/UI_WPF/level23/23_3.php)
- [msdn.com](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/bb384311(v=vs.110).aspx)

Лично я предпочитаю фреймы окнам. Так практичнее.